# Return Table and Form in page callback

Tags: forms, routes

I have a problem returning table and form in page callback at the same time it only works if one of them only returned.

```
function _table_maps(){
$query = db_select('maps','m');

$result = $query->fields('m')
                ->extend('TableSort')
                ->extend('PagerDefault') 
                ->limit(50)
                ->execute(); 

$header = array('Title','Longitude','Latitude','Description');

$rows = array();
while($data = $result->fetchAssoc())
{
    $rows[] = array(
        $data['maps_title'],
        $data['maps_long'],
        $data['maps_lat'],
        $data['maps_desc']
    );
}

$output = theme_table(
            array(
                "header" => $header,
                "rows" => $rows,
                "attributes" => array(),
                "sticky" => true, 
                "caption" => "",
                "colgroups" => array(),
                "empty" => t("Table has no row!")
                )
            ).theme("pager");

return $output;
```

}

```
function aieadmin_map_form($form_state){

$form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#description' => t('Enter the Title For the Location'),
);

$form['long'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Longitude'),
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#description' => t('Enter the Longitude For the Location'),
);

$form['lat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Latitude'),
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#description' => t('Enter the Latitude For the Location'),
);

$form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Describe it'),
    '#cols' => 60,
    '#rows' => 5,
    '#description' => t('Location description.'),
);

$form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Save'));

return $form; 
}
```

/****************Page Callbacks*******************/

```
function aieadmin_callback_mod(){
$page = _table_maps();
$page .= drupal_get_form('aieadmin_map_form');
return $page;
}
```

Comment: can you return table and form separately?

Answer (score 0):

try this in the form

```
$custom_table = _table_maps();

$form['some_information'] = array(
  '#markup' => $custom_table,
  '#prefix' => '<div class="custom-class">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on how to do this in Drupal 8/9: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/drupal-form-api-ajax-form-and-results-same-page